# Which measuring is the correct one?

Tags: measurement

Just noticed that the Measure tool on the left and the Measurement of Edge Lengths under Overlays give different results, here - 3.65 and 3.76791.
EDIT - something is completely wrong there, just look at the vertical measurement which shows 31.6131 :-O

I'm using v3.4.1 on Linux.
Is that expected?

[image]

Comment: Does the object have unapplied scale?  Scale should be 1,1,1 you can Ctrl+A and apply scale if needed.

Comment: @AllenSimpson awww yes, thanks a lot! Going to read more about it, forgot to mention I'm still a beginner. Please add the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The measure tool measures world space, where these measurements are taking the object's *Scale* into account.  You can apply the object's scale to reset it.

In *Object Mode* with the object selected, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> for the apply menu and select *Scale*.